# hide scrollbar but keep scroll functionality in react.js

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried all methods for vanilla HTML, JS and CSS but it don't seem to work and when it does its not responsive for instance when I reduce the screen it hides but if its Maximized it shows up

Please is there away to solve this issue in material-ui and reactjs

is there a way to make it compatible with various browsers too?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This worked for me, i created an external CSS file just like plain HTML and CSS and then linked it to the react file. It's also cross platform.

```
.parentDiv{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.childDiv{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -20px;
    right: -20px; 
    overflow: scroll;
 }
```

if that's too long for you, try this shorter method in your CSS file:

```
*{
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `webkit-scrollbar` shouldn't be used in production and is a non standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 8):

**In 2021:**

Add in App.css, and import App.css into App.js

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

According to the [spec](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp), you can hide the scroll bars and keep the functionality in some browsers with this:

```
/* Hide scrollbar for Chrome, Safari and Opera */
.example::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide scrollbar for IE and Edge */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
}
```

Comment: `webkit-scrollbar` shouldn't be used in production and is a non standard.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using MUI styled components, you can use it while defining the custom element as well,

```js
const MyScrollingElement = styled(Box)(() => ({
    overflow: "auto",
    scrollbarWidth: "none", // Hide the scrollbar for firefox
    '&::-webkit-scrollbar': {
        display: 'none', // Hide the scrollbar for WebKit browsers (Chrome, Safari, Edge, etc.)
    },
    '&-ms-overflow-style:': {
        display: 'none', // Hide the scrollbar for IE
    },
}));
```

From the above snippet, its obvious "scrollbarWidth" is most semantic way of doing it, however as pointed out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar) it only supports firefox browser for now.
For chrome and other webkit based browsers, we have to follow the non-standard way of controlling pseudo-elements.

Try it out [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_hide_scrollbars.asp).

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me on IE and Chrome. Nothing worked for firefox(79.0), a hack could be to make it transparent.

#### CSS

```css
.scrollhost::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.scrollhost ::-moz-scrollbar {
  display: none;
 
}

.scrollhost {
  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-color: transparent transparent; /*just hides the scrollbar for firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0;
}
```