# How to hide scroll bar in react app with allowing scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to hide scrollbar in my react app but not being able to achieve it. I tried using
`::-webkit-scrollbar` with `width as 0` or `display as none` but not able to achieve the desired result.

Comment: use `overflow:none`

Comment: What do you mean by `not being able to achieve it.`? Prevent it from scrolling or not showing it on screen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide scroll bar, but while still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hide scrollbar but keep scroll functionality in react.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60329344/hide-scrollbar-but-keep-scroll-functionality-in-react-js)

Answer (score 5):

This will work for all browsers. Here the `container` div is scrollable but the scrollbar is hidden what you are trying to acheive.

```css
.container {
  height: 200px;
  width: 350px;
  background-color: #3c3c3c;
  overflow-y: auto;
  
  /* hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  scrollbar-width: none;
}

/* hide scrollbar for chrome, safari and opera */
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.container p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
  <p>hello</p>
</div>
```